# Modifiy variable values in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Let's say

```
CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=abc/xyz
```

And .gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  VAR: ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
```

Is there a way to remove 'abc/' from the value of CI_COMMIT_BRANCH within the .gitlab-ci.yml so that the value of VAR finally becomes 'xyz'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the workaround described in [issue 27921](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/27921#note_38132416) could work:

```yaml
variables:
  CI_SHORT_COMMIT_SHA: '$${CI_COMMIT_SHA:0:8}'
  FOO_BAR: '$${FOO}-$${BAR}'

before_script:
  - eval export CI_SHORT_COMMIT_SHA=${CI_SHORT_COMMIT_SHA}
  - eval export FOO_BAR=${FOO_BAR}

test:
  script:
    - echo ${CI_SHORT_COMMIT_SHA}
    - echo ${FOO_BAR}
```

In your case:

```yaml
variables:
  VAR:  $$(eval echo "${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}" | sed "s,^.\+\?/,," ) 

before_script:
  - eval export VAR=${VAR}

test:
  script:
    - echo ${VAR}
```

Comment: Thanks! Think my question is not precise enough as i don't need to change the value of CI_COMMIT_BRANCH. I only need the modified value for VAR. Also, the regex part does not work for me.

Comment: @cnmuc Then same idea, but with VAR.

Comment: yes, sure, u are right, it does not matter, but removing 'abc/' did not work

Comment: @cnmuc OK. I have replace the regex part, to remove abc/, with a sed command.